# Disable warnings and errors in react parcel application in production

Tags: reactjs, console, warnings, parcel

I have a React application bundled with Parcel, and I want to disable all warnings and errors in the production build to ensure a cleaner console for end-users. Currently, I see various warnings and errors in the console, which I'd like to suppress.

What steps or configurations should I follow to achieve this in my Parcel-based React project? I want to make sure that all warnings and errors are not shown when users access the production version of the application.

Thank you for your help!